# "Insufficient Privileges error" while implementing sso (single sign-on) between multiple orgs

Tags: single-sign-on

I am implementing sso for my client, but I am getting the insufficient privileges error repeatedly while clicking on the SSO name while logging in Service provider (or by clicking the "**IdP-Initiated Login URL**").

I am working in my client's Identity Provider and Service Provider org using License Management App and using **system administrator** as profile in connected app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a day with this, just figured it out that it was throwing the error because I was logged in using LMS as subscriber.

So, even after being logged in as system administrator there was no full privileges to the user so that it can login to another salesforce org using single sign-on.